# Is there a way to optimize the query if we are using ROUND function 100 times in a single query

Tags: oracle, query-performance, optimization, oracle-11g

The below query is to compare the last day of the month and select either zero or a value.
I am not pasting the entire query as its huge and the i am just pasting the condition which if possible can be optimized.

The fields M_H_REP_DATE , M_F_CCFRMCCD1 , M_F_CCFRMCD2  are dates and are  getting compared with date , and  GAP.M_F_CCNOM is of float(21,2) format

```
ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,0)) >= 
M_F_CCFRMCD1 and
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,0)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then 
GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_0M

ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,1)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,1)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_1M

ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,2)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,2)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_2M

ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,3)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,3)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_3M
ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,4)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,4)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_4M
ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,5)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,5)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_5M   
ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,6)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,6)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_6M
ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,7)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,7)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_7M    
ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,8)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,8)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_8M   
ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,9)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,9)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_9M    
ROUND(sum(case when LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,10)) >= M_F_CCFRMCD1 and 
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TD.M_H_REP_DATE,10)) < M_F_CCFRMCD2 then GAP.M_F_CCNOM else 0 end )) as 
M_10M
```

The above line is repeated  for 40 times , since we have to add 34 months .
but the output is same for all conditions , its either GAP.M_F_CCNOM or O.

Is there a way to optimize the above query?
I am new to sql and could only manage the above query.

Thanks

`

Comment: columns `M_F_CCFRMCD1` and `GAP.M_F_CCNOM` data type date?

Comment: No  M_F_CCFRMCCD1 is date as its getting compared with date , since iam rounding the output the data type is float

Comment: Can you explain what this actually wants to achieve ? What are those dates ? What do they mean ?

Comment: In general the use of that many embedded functions, both in the columns and the predicate, will not be good for performance. How many rows does this query return, and how up-to-the-second does the result set need to be? Could you make this a materialized view and refresh it periodically?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind , i am adding monts to a specific day  and then comparing whether it is between 2 dates and selecting a number (float) as output.

Comment: @pmdba : the query here is just a part of huge query which is takng 20 minutes o run and its returning only 700 rows

Comment: @Sai I know what the code does. i would like to understand that this is expected to achieve. What **business** question is this query expected to achieve. What is the **meaning** of the dates (TD.M_H_REP_DATE, M_F_CCFRMCD1,  M_F_CCFRMCD2) ?

Comment: What is the explain plan (execution path) for the query?

Comment: See here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-explain-the-explain-plan-052011-393674.pdf